# Android code to retrieve data from firebase

Tags: java, android

Below is the data present in firebase. I have to retrieve only path field in employee and store it in array in android

```
 myfirebaselink
     user
      employee
        -KAZY5627P4MjLBa3Ae-
          DateTime: "2016-02-15 16:18:20"
          Latitude: "11.0318354"
          Longitude: "11.0318354"
          Path: "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0070.JPG"
          Seqno: "1"
       -KAZZcBscTCAon8ShoXa
          DateTime: "2016-02-15 16:25:02"
          Latitude: "11.0318501"
          Longitude: "11.0318501"
          Path: "/storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100ANDRO/DSC_0071.JPG"
          Seqno: "2"
```

code :

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "data change",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                System.out.println("There are " + arg0.getChildrenCount()+ " blog posts");  

                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : arg0.getChildren()) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "call blogpost",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    BlogPost post = postSnapshot.getValue(BlogPost.class);

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "getting value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    System.out.println(post.getLatitude() + " - " + post.getSeqno());
                    tv1.setText(post.getLatitude() + " - " + post.getSeqno());
                }
            }
```

BlogPsot is a class contains get and set methods.
I have tried the method which is present in firebase.com but it doesn't work for me. Can anyone help me

Comment: Better to paste the code you tried and show any traceback, or explain what it means to say 'it doesn't work for me'

Comment: yes sir I added the code